# How to write bits to file c++

Tags: c++, qt

I have a c++ qt program. And I want to write data to a file. But I want to do by bits. When I write data to a text file, each character weighs 1 byte, which is not very suitable for me. Is it possible to write bits to a file (not necessarily text) in c++.

Comment: An individual bit is not writable or addressable in a file. You need to pack 8 bits into a byte and write that. Or possibly more bits into larger sized data type.

Comment: Ok, can you tell me how to do it right?

Comment: How do you have bits in the first place? How are you storing them in your current code?

Comment: At the moment I just have numbers (char) that are written to a plain text file. I want to convert them to binary code and write them to a file.

Comment: Could you edit your post to give more context about why you want to do this? It sounds as if what you want is a binary output, not necessarily a bitwise one. What, precisely, is the data you want to store?

Comment: I am making a packaging program. And I need to reduce the size of the file as much as possible. Yes, I just need to write the binary values ​​to the file. That is, let's say there is a number 1. If I write it to a plain text file, then I get a size of 1 byte. And if I write in binary code, I can fit 8 units in one byte.

Comment: @РостиславРоманец how are those "binary values" (whatever this is) stored?

Comment: at the moment it is int. But I want to convert it to the binary system and write it to a file to reduce the file size. But then I have a question. Let's say I want to write down the number 1 and the number 3. In binary, it will look like this: 1 and 11. But when I want to read this file, the computer will not be able to understand what this number is, since 111 is the number 7.

Answer (score 3):

Since you mention Qt, you could use a [QBitArray](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbitarray.html). It has an `operator<<` overload, so you can output to a stream.

```
QBitArray ba;
ba.resize(3);
ba[0] = true;
ba[1] = false;
ba[2] = true;

QFile file("file.dat");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
QDataStream out(&file);
out << ba;
```